# how to get output value using stdin and stdout in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, data-science

I've used the below code but I can't get the output.

```
from scipy.stats import norm
prob = norm.pdf(0.5, m, s)

import sys
sys.stdin.readline()
print(sys.stdinreadin())

def input:
    print("Enter any value")
```

I need to find the probability (`prob`) when I input a number. Any suggestions?

Comment: format your code.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're trying to do. Are you trying to find the f(x) for a given input value x (from standard input) where f is the PDF of a normal distribution? What are m and s?

Comment: yes, m = mean and s = std deviation

Comment: I suggest you read a Python manual.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could write something simple like:

```
from scipy.stats import norm

mean = int(input("Give me the mean: "))
std_dev = int(input("Give me the standard deviation: "))

prob = norm.pdf(0.5, mean, std_dev)

print(prob)
```

There are other ways to do this, like creating a function, but without knowing what you want to do exactly, it's hard to know - except that you want to get the probability. Nonetheless, this should do.